# Inserting into db while iterating through cursor

Tags: android, database, sqlite, insert, android-cursor

I have a cursor that contains 3 columns from my database. I need to iterate through, and add the IDs to another table. I tried using the code below, but it caused an "Application not responding" message, and took about 10 seconds to insert all the rows (about 1000).

I have changed the code so that I iterate through the cursor and insert into the DB separately, and this now takes about 500ms. Although it seems I have fixed my problem, I don't understand why.

Can someone please explain why the code below takes so long to execute?

```
public void setNowPlayingSongs(SQLiteDatabase db, Cursor cursor) {
    // Clear all the current songs
    db.delete(TABLE_NOW_PLAYING, null, null);

    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cursor.moveToFirst();

    int index = cursor.getColumnIndex(COL_ID);

    while (!cursor.isAfterLast()){
        cv.put(COL_SONG_ID, cursor.getInt(index));
        db.insert(TABLE_NOW_PLAYING, null, cv);
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }

}
```

And why this is so much faster? I don't understand why it's faster to loop through the cursor and then loop through a list. I thought the method above should be faster?

```
public void setNowPlayingSongs(SQLiteDatabase db, Cursor cursor) {
    ContentValues cv;
    List<Integer> ids;
    int index;

    // Clear all the current songs
    db.delete(TABLE_NOW_PLAYING, null, null);

    // Check which column holds the IDs
    index = cursor.getColumnIndex(COL_ID);

    // Add the ids to a list
    ids = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    cursor.moveToFirst();        
    while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
        ids.add(cursor.getInt(index));
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }

    // Insert the IDs into the now playing table.
    cv = new ContentValues();
    db.beginTransaction();
    for (Integer id : ids) {
        cv.put(COL_SONG_ID, id);
        db.insert(TABLE_NOW_PLAYING, null, cv);
    }
    db.setTransactionSuccessful();
    db.endTransaction();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do individual inserts, each one is actually wrapped in a SQLite transaction. If you instead perform all of your inserts in a single transaction, this should speed things up substantially.

```
db.beginTransaction();
try {
    // do your inserts

    db.setTransactionSuccessful();
} finally {
    db.endTransaction();
}
```

Comment: I actually did this and although it sped it up, it was still taking about 6 or 7 seconds. The only thing that really worked was to loop through the cursor first (adding the ids to a list), and then looping through the list to do the db insertion, but I don't understand why looping through 1000 ids *twice* is faster then my original method

Comment: Using raw insert statements will drastically improve performance @karakuri

Comment: @arul You are sort of correct. You can make this faster by using a [`SQLiteStatement`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteStatement.html) and binding new values with each iteration. Normally `SQLiteDatabase` has to prepare the statement and bind the arguments, so you save by not having the prepare the same statement over and over again.